# General Parcelable Object (is it possible)?

Tags: java, android, reflection, parcelable, parcel

Hello i am trying to create a class called ParcelableObject in which i implement the Parcelable interface.

Then i will create other objects, which they will extend ParcelableObject.
I am doing it because i don't want to write the methods of Parcelable interface in each object.

As for now i have managed to do this for Objects containing other Objects (which all of them extend the ParcelableObject class) and for primitive Types.

I am having troubles doing it for Arrays and List of primitive Types and of course Arrays and Lists of Objects

I intend to expand this to cover Lists, Arrays.

The way i did it is by getting all the fields of the object given

So here is my question.
First of all
Is this possible?
Second i tried to expand it for arrays or lists of primitive types and i fail to do it.
To be more specific. Now i am trying to expand it to Arrays of Integers, or Lists of Integers.
As i see i fail to read from the parcel a List of Integers because i get cast errors etc.
So any help would be grateful.

Also the basic idea around this is to store to the ParcelableObject the object of its subclass.
Then if i get an object (not primitive type) i write its class name to parcel and then the object.
So when i want to read an object from the parcel, i read first the string with its class name, make a new instance of the class using (Class.forName() etc) and then assign the object read from parcel to the Object instantiated above. If there is any better way to get the Class Name of the ParcelableObject's subclass other than filling the parcel unnecessary Strings id like to know.

Here is the ParcelableObject.java
You can download the whole android ParcelableObject project to test it. Demonstration is included.
Tested it under virtual device Nexus S (4.2). Project is targeted to work for 4.0 and above.

https://github.com/tchar/ParcelableObject/blob/master/ParcelableObject/src/com/parcelableobject/ParcelableObject.java

UPDATE*** Added Support for primitive Object Lists.
Still having problems with primitive types (int, etc) not with Integers and list of ParcelableObjects

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the [`Serializable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface? It does a lot of what you're trying to do here. The point of implementing the `Parcelable` methods is to make serialization _fast_.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i am familiar with the Serializable interface. I dont use it because its slow on Android (i did use it one time long ago). I am familiar how parcels and the parcelable interface works. I just want to find a way to avoid writing many lines of code in each object. Especially when objects are complicated implementing the parcelable interface is time consuming. So you say that the only way that parcels are so fast in android is that you explicitly declare what you want to write to the parcel? Is this what im trying to make gonna be as slow as Serializable?

Comment: Effectively, yeah, you're reproducing what Serializable does. Reflection based solutions are slow - explicit construction as in the way Parcelable works is [much, _much_ faster](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/).

Comment: Oh i see. I am doing this to avoid writing tones of code each time i want to pass an object to another activity. So a better solution would be to write something like a code generator. I will give it the classes i want to implement the Parcelable interface and it will add to my code the implementation of the needed methods and CREATORS. So ill be having the same automated way to pass an object but it will be faster since all the work is gonna be before compilation right?

Comment: Code generation is probably the way to go, but it looks like [others](http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2013/01/22/parcelabler-helps-you-create-parcelable-implementations-for-your-android-classes/) have [already](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin) done [exactly that](http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2011/04/parcelgen-a-code-generator-for-android-data-objects.html). If you decide to write your own, make sure you consider the [relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1319/).